# icc version 13.0.0 flags for compiling

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I have a project written in c++ that I compile locally using g++ version 4.8.4 with following code

```
g++ BasicModel.cpp -std=c++11x -O3
```

I am trying to submit this file to a cluster to run large numbers of parallel simulations and to do this i need to compile the code on the cluster. g++ compiler on the cluster is out of data so i'm forced to use ICC compiler version 13.0.0

when run with the following

ICC BasicModel.cpp -O3

This however does not recognise lots of the c++11 syntax i've used. Are their flags i could use to avoid this or do i need to rewrite my code?

Answer (score 0):

`-std=c++11x` is wrong it should be `-std=c++11`.

Comment: icpc -std=c++11 depends on the support which the g++ on path provides for that option.